# Why $(n^x +n^{x+2})$ is divisible by $5$ for some $n$ and not for others.

Tags: decimal-expansion

Why for numbers with last digits $0, 2, 3, 5, 7$ and $8, (n^x +n^{x+2})/5$ is a whole number and for numbers with last digits $1, 4, 6$ and $9, (n^x +n^{x+2})/5$ is not a whole number?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If the last digit of $n$ is divisible by $5$ then $n^x$ and $n^{x+2}$ are both divisible by $5$, so their sum is.  If $n\equiv2\pmod5$ then $n^x+n^{x+2}\equiv n^x(1+2^2)\equiv0\pmod5$; if $n\equiv3\pmod5$ then $n^x+n^{x+2}\equiv n^x(1+3^2)\equiv0\pmod5$

Answer (score 1):

Because $n$ is congruent to its last digit modulo $10$, hence also modulo $5$, and because in the factorisation
$$n^x+n^{x+2}=n^x(1+n^2),$$
you can check the second factor is congruent to $0\bmod 5$ only if the digit is $2,3,7,8$, and the first factor is divisible by $5$ if and only if the last digit is $0$ or $5$.